# Get date format given datetime string and date

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

Say I have date and time information for some event, plus a matching date string that could be in any format, how can I get the format of the date string (e.g. `YYYY MM DD HH:mm`)?

#### Example

**If I have:**

```
var date = new Date(2006, 0, 2, 15, 4, 0, 0);

var dateString1 = "Monday, January 2, 2006 15:04"
var dateString2 = "02 Jan 2006 - 3:04PM"
```

**How do I get:**

```
var dateFormat1 = "dddd, MMMM D, YYYY HH:mm"
var dateFormat2 = "DD MMM YYYY - H:MMA"
```

#### Example in context

I have the HTML element `<time datetime="2020-02-11T20:00:00+0000">11 Feb • 20h00</time>`. I want to take the time from the datetime attribute, add one hour (or some other manipulation), then output it in whatever format is in the inner text. In this example the output would be `11 Feb • 21h00`. Any format in the inner text is possible.

**Bonus:**

Even better if I could also handle timezones or UTC offsets, e.g.

```
var dateString3 = "Monday, January 2, 2006 15:04 MST"
var dateString4 = "Monday, January 2, 2006 15:04 -0700"

var dateFormat3 = "dddd, MMMM D, YYYY HH:mm z"
var dateFormat4 = "dddd, MMMM D, YYYY HH:mm ZZ"
```

I imagine some complicated regular expression could do the trick, but is there a more elegant method?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/386424). What is your end goal? Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Do you have a limited combinations of formats? If so enumerate over them, create the formatted string from the `date` instance, and check if it is equal to the incoming string.

Comment: @Igor, I'd like to manipulate the inner text of `<time>` elements, which can be in any format. I'd like the new datetime to be displayed in the original format.

Comment: you could try [moment js parsing](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) and if successful then read the `.format` property of the resulting instance. However you decide to end up doing this just know it is going to be very error prone.

Comment: `parsedTime.creationData().format` and `parsedTime._f` only gives a value if: **(1)** the format string was provided to the parse function (e.g. `moment("02 Jan 2005 15:04", "DD MMM YYYY HH:mm")` _or_ **(2)**  if the time is in ISO format (e.g. `moment("2020-02-18T21:11:09+00:00")`). In any other case it's undefined. In fact, calling `moment()` on a non-RFC2822 or non-ISO format falls back to `Date()` and gives a deprecation warning.

Comment: Well I guess that should tell you something. If it is not included in a robust date/time library like `moment` then if I were you I would think twice before trying to implement this requirement.

Comment: This requires parsing the input what you think might be its components, then trying to figure out the order they've been presented in. For some formats, it's impossible to determine, e.g. 12/11/19 might be 12 November, 11 December or 19 November. The year is also ambiguous. You might be able to get it to work for a subset of possible formats, but certainly not all in use.

Comment: @RobG, that's true if the date and time are unknown. In this case, I do have the date and time information (e.g. `var date = new Date(2006, 0, 2, 15, 4, 0, 0)`), so ambiguity is not an issue.

Comment: For `<time>` elements to be valid, they must either define a `datetime` attribute with the date in a valid format, or the text inside the element itself must have the date in a valid format. None of the formats in your question are considered valid for the `<time>` element according to the [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time).

Comment: @Robyn—sure, but there are still some date formats that jumble the values to make parsing difficult even if you know the values you're looking for if the same value appears for two or more parts. "Civll" timezone offset names are also fraught as there's no standard for them and there are duplicates (e.g. CST and EST) and different names and abbreviations for the same timezone.

Comment: @fubar, here's a more complete example: I have `<time datetime="2020-02-11T20:00:00+0000">11 Feb • 20h00</time>`. I want to take the time from the datetime attribute, add one hour, then output it in whatever format is in the inner text, so in this example the output would be `11 Feb • 21h00`.

Comment: @Robyn, that latest example actually makes sense now. I think you should add that to your question to clarify what you're trying to do. Is the date format always random? Or are there a finite number of formats used in the source data?

Comment: @fubar, example added. Yes, the date format is anything a user can dream up.

Comment: @RobG, yes a date like `12/12/12 12:12` would indeed be ambiguous.

Comment: And out of curiosity, why can you not just standardise the date/time format when you write the modifed value back to the `<time>` element?

Comment: @fubar, the format is specified by the user and I'd like to keep it that way.

Comment: So if the format is specified by the user, why can't you just access their preference? It must be saved somewhere if they've chosen it. Likewise, that suggests a finite list of options.

Comment: The format is specified as a [Go layout string](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format) in a Hugo template. In the end, I used Hugo's replace function to convert the Go layout string to a `moment.js` style format string and saved is a data attribute in the `<time>` element. I'm still interested in an answer, just out of curiosity.

Comment: That was exactly what I was about to suggest. Glad you found a solution. As for a solution to your original question, I doubt anyone will post one. Given the number different format combinations that could exist, it would be extremely slow to calculate all possibilities and test them all against the current value.